# Cannot import org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite, spring-4

My IDE is `Spring Tool Suite`. I want to use the `NumberUtils.isNumber` function. STS does not know the class , and there is no suggestion of import in the error icon. My buildpath is using java-se 1.6 :

[image]

In pom.xml java-version is 1.7 :

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>
</properties>
```

So how to make the import possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache libraries doesn't come inbuilt with conventional java libraries. You have to add them. Add this dependency to `pom.xml` to access that method.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[source](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0)